# IntelliJ 14 Gradle task in Test Runner

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-14

Upgraded to `IntelliJ 14.0.1`  One of the big new features I was looking for:

"*If you run tests via a Gradle task, the IDE offers you the standard Test Runner instead of the console output.*" (Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#buildTools)

I right click on the Gradle Task to run our Integration Tests:

[image]

However, I see the results of the test still going to console output, not to the Test Runner:

[image]

Has anyone been able to get this new feature in IntelliJ IDEA 14 to work?

Thank you in advance,

Philip

Comment: Anyone know if this feature is supposed to be in Android Studio 1.0 as well? I can't get it working anyway, even though my task is named "test" (using Robolectric and android-unit-test-plugin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like IntelliJ looks for a task named "test" rather than a task of type `Test`.

https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/gradle/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/execution/test/runner/GradleTestsExecutionConsoleManager.java#L191

Comment: Wow, thanks for that very in-depth research into their gradle plugin source code.

Comment: That was it, your answer is correct (accepted it). I ran a Gradle task named "test" in IntelliJ 14 and saw that it started the Test Runner.  *sigh* seems to me that they should have added more flexibility ... I opened a ticket with Jetbrains

Comment: @PhilipTenn can you please give a link to your ticket? I want to upvote it.

Comment: the ticket is closed but I still have the problem now on IDEA 15!

Answer (score 0):

Rename the `test` task to `unitTest` and then create a wrapper that runs both:

```
// Rename test to unitTest
tasks.test.name = "unitTest"

// Wrap and run both
task test(dependsOn:['unitTest', 'integrationTest'])
```

If you only want to run integration tests, just overwrite it:

```
task test(overwrite: true, dependsOn: ['integrationTest'])
```

This allows me to run the integration tests in the test runner successfully (at least it works in IDEA 15 EAP but it should work in 14 as well I would think).

Answer (score 0):

I still get this in IntelliJ 2017.1, but specifically when running tests in the gradle `buildSrc` directory. After digging a while, it turns out that the Gradle API doesn’t expose the test tasks in the special `buildSrc` directory to Intellij, so IntelliJ doesn’t recognize it as a test.

Workaround: Open another IntellIJ project for the `buildSrc` directory directory instead of trying to run tests cleanly inside the root project.